# Accessing javascript array values using PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have created an array named "arrayModel" in Javascript and I am trying to access those values in PHP. So as to store those values to PHP variables.

```
var arrayModel = new Array(5);
arrayModel[0] = "one";
arrayModel[1] = "two";
arrayModel[2] = "three";
arrayModel[3] = "four";
arrayModel[4] = "five";
```

Any idea how I can access the values of the array in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific? As it is you are only initiating an empty array of length 5, are you populating this array with values? How? Are you sending this array back to a backend in PHP? What have you tried so far to access values in this array?

Comment: There will be information stored in the array. Then, I am trying to retrieve those values in the array from PHP.

Comment: JavaScript runs in the browser. PHP runs on the server. PHP therefore *can't* access your JS at all. But your JS can use Ajax to submit the required values to your PHP page.

Comment: The only way I can think of is by sending a request from client to server side

Comment: What do you mean "from PHP"? Does the array get sent to your PHP method properly? If you simply wish to access indices of an array in PHP you can use $arrayName[i]. If you wish to POST your info from JS frontend client to PHP backend server there are a multitude of ways, AJAX for example. What is your exact question here?

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server language and javascript is a browser language. That means they are not working together. So whatever you write in the javascript will be only in the browser, only when you send it to the server with for example AJAX then PHP can do something with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AJAX` to do that

First, you should `json stringify` it

`var arrayModel= JSON.stringify(arrayModel);`

Then pas it via AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {yourData: arrayModel},
    dataType: 'html',
    url: 'yourPHPFile.php'
});
```

Then in your PHP file access like

```
$yourData =json_decode($_POST['yourData']);
```